# Deleting Specific Item From Array in React using Functional Components/Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to delete an item in an array. However, my delete button is not executing my code and the array remains unchanged. I am not sure what to do.

My code is below:

```
//App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Overview from "./components/Overview";

function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    setTask(e.target.value);
  }

  function onSubmitTask(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTasks(tasks.concat(task));
    setTask("");
  }

  //error happening here????---------------------------------------------------
  function removeTask(itemId) {
      setTasks(prevState => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId));
  }


  return (
    <div className="col-6 mx-auto mt-5">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitTask}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="taskInput">Enter task</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={task}
            type="text"
            id="taskInput"
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Add Task
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Overview tasks={tasks} removeTask={removeTask} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child Component:

```
import React from "react";

function Overview(props) {
  const { tasks, removeTask } = props;
  console.log(tasks)
  return (
    <>
      {tasks.map((task, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p key={index}>
              #{index + 1} {task}
            </p>
            //this onClick isn't doing anything-------------------------------------
            <button onClick={() => removeTask(index)}>Delete Task</button>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
export default Overview;
```

My 'tasks' state gives me an array, with items inside as strings. However, when I tried to filter the array, that didn't work. So instead of filtering by value, I tried to filter by id/index. Since the index would match it I thought that would remove the item from the array, even if there is just one item, it doesn't remove anything and the delete button just console logs the given array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the `taskId` instead of `index` here

```
<button onClick={() => removeTask(task.id /*index*/)}>Delete Task</button>
```

because `removeTask` function is dealing with `taskId` not with the `index`

---

However it's looks like you don't have `id` field on `tasks` even though you assuming it is there in `setTasks(prevState => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId));`, so if you want to keep removing task by index, change `removeTask` as below.

```
function removeTask(index) { // remove by index
    setTasks(prevState => {
        const tasks = [...prevState]; // create new array based on current tasks
        tasks.splice(index, 1); // remove task by index
        return tasks; // return altered array
    });
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xeggf7)

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

Your delete method consumes an item id, but you pass it an index in the button's `onClick` handler.

## Solution

Choose one or the other of `id` or index, and remain consistent.

Using `id`

```
function removeTask(itemId) {
  setTasks(prevState => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId));
}

...

<button onClick={() => removeTask(task.id)}>Delete Task</button>
```

Using index

```
function removeTask(itemIndex) {
  setTasks(prevState => prevState.filter((_, index) => index !== itemIndex));
}

...

<button onClick={() => removeTask(index)}>Delete Task</button>
```

Since it doesn't appear your tasks are objects with an `id` property I suggest adding an `id` to your tasks. This will help you later when you successfully delete a task from you list since you'll also want to ***not*** use the array index as the react key since you expect to mutate your tasks array.

App.js

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

function onSubmitTask(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTasks(prevTasks => prevTasks.concat({
    id: uuidV4(), // <-- generate new id
    task
  }));
  setTask("");
}

function removeTask(itemId) {
  setTasks(prevState => prevState.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId));
}
```

Child

```
function Overview({ tasks, removeTask }) {
  return (
    {tasks.map(({ id, task }, index) => { // <-- destructure id & task
      return (
        <Fragment key={id}> // <-- react key on outer-most element
          <p>
            #{index + 1} {task}
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => removeTask(id)}>Delete Task</button>
        </>
      );
    })}
  );
}
```